# Android drawing program

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I'd like to learn android programming, I already know java, and I have already compiled all the simple "Hello world" tutorial apps I could.

I want to do something with a basic touchscreen interaction, and canvas drawing. Just "get the touch position and draw a dot there".

Can you recommend some tutorial about graphics/canvas on Android? I just want to get started, knowing all do's and don'ts for a simple situation such as this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780367/is-there-source-code-available-for-any-drawing-applicationlike-paint-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably encounter the [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) system. Therefore you should start with [this](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html) tutorial series, where you will learn how to interact using [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Answer (score 1):

Below link might help you http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html

Comment: The link is not available anymore. If you can find the original source somehow, please try to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look [here in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)